# I have written one code in python 2 now i want to execute this in python3, i am getting error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        import pymysql
        import pandas as pd
        db='mysql+pymysql://developer:11111@192.168.1.11:3306/pos'
        db_connection=create_engine(db)
        df=pd.read_sql_table(table_name='product2', con=db_connection)
        #df1=pd.read_sql_table(table_name='product', con=db_connection)
        start_date = '2009-10-19 00:00:00'
        end_date = '2010-10-19 23:59:59'
        mask = (df['DateCreated'] > start_date) & (df['DateCreated'] <= end_date) #DateFilter
        df = df.loc[mask]
        t_type=(df['TherapyType']=='C')
        df = df.loc[t_type]
        df


     i am getting this error :-

            ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
            <ipython-input-1-5c4885ab0640> in <module>
                  1 #extract the data from the created table in which dataframe was inserted..
            ----> 2 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
                  3 import pymysql
                  4 import pandas as pd
                  5 db='mysql+pymysql://developer:devdev@192.168.1.44:3306/pos'

            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

I have written a code in python 2 i want to execute this code in python 3 but i am getting error, i am not able to understand what should i do

Comment: Do you have sqlalchemy installed for Python 3?

Comment: no , but now i have installed sqlalchemy for py3

Comment: how do you run this code? are you using IPython? can you please provide the header shown when IPython is run? (the text written right after executing `ipython` command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo pip3 install sqlalchemy,

sudo pip3 install PyMySQL,
```

I installed `sqlalchemy` and `pymysql` using these two commands and now I'm not getting any error.